# While Loop while(1) vs while(3) or any digit for that matter

Tags: loops, while-loop, do-while

When using the while loop what does it mean to write `while(1)` vs any other digit?

In my program `while(1)` is giving me the same answers as `while(3)`

```
int num1;
int loopcount;

while(1) {
    printf("enter your positive number:");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    if(num1>0) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In C, any integer value other than `0` is treated as `true` for conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

In C, 0 can mean 'false' in certain contexts, and non-zero can mean 'true'.